# Expand Element, Close button and remove arrow

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to display a expand button on my wordpress site. I currently have:

```
[expand title="<img src='http://homeofdrone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Read-More-Button.png' />" tag="div" alt="continue button" notitle="true" trigclass="my_center_class"][/expand]
```

This creates the button and centers it, GREAT! However it still displays the arrow on the left hand side, and the button remains. How do I make it so the arrow on the left isn't showing, AND when the button is clicked and the content is expanded, to hide the button so the content is there until the page is reloaded :)

Comment: anyone able to help me?

Comment: Your code is some sort of shortcode, not the actual html. So no one can understand what you arrow on the left hand side or how the code is structured. Please edit your post and update the html related to the section. To hide and expand part of the content, it may or may not need javascript or  css codes, what have you done on that. Post it here and revised your question to be more specific.